# Tizen Web application : Watch and Application

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

Is it possible to create Tizen Web application that combines `Web Watch` and `Web application` in one. Where can I found this info?

Comment: You can communicate within apps using different ways.... you don't need to combine these... https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/communication-between-two-web-apps-using-app-control-tizen

Comment: https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/sending-bundle-over-message-port

Comment: https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/communication-within-tizen-hybrid-app

Comment: but this means that user should install 2 apps instead one.

Comment: No! if you package your app with multi option ...it will generate a single wgt

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to create Tizen Web application that combines Web Watch and Web application in one. Where can I found this info?

=> Yes. **You can create a package consisting of two application**(Web application and Web Watch application). Please refer to the link below.
https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/packaging-hybrid-application?langredirect=1

But, you probably will not be able to register it in the Samsung Galaxy store due to the policy. There are several policies for application registration. For example, widget application should be packaged with UI application.

I don't know about that exactly. If you need, contact Samsung seller office.
https://seller.samsungapps.com